# JSON.parse: Unexpected character error in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

I am trying to parse a JSON which I will get from Java session variable. I am using code like this:

```
var foo1 = <%= session.getAttribute("json").toString() %>
var foo = JSON.parse(foo1.toString());
alert(foo.toString());
```

(Yes, I know scriptlets is Bad, but this is just for temporary). The value which I get with `foo1` is a valid JSON (I verified with online validators). But when I try to alert the `foo1` I get it as [object,Object] but if I try to parse, I get `JSON.parse:Unexcpected character` error.

I have uploaded JSON [here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3959), in-case if required. Since it is a bit big json string, I cannot post here.

Can someone please help me to know what wrong I am doing in this? To summary I am trying to get JSON String from Java session variable and trying to parse it in Javascript. Any tips on how to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
var foo = <%= session.getAttribute("json").toString() %>
alert(foo.toString());
```

Reason : your are already getting json object so no need to parse.

```
var obj = {id:1};    // No need to parse
var obj = "{id:1}"; // Need to parse
```

Comment: So then I can be able to access elements just like it has been parsed? right?

Comment: it's again printing me as "[object,Object]"

Comment: ok I will do my bit research again and comeback and reply to you, thanks :)

Comment: according to me foo is array so try alert(foo[0].toString())

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `foo1` is not a string but already a JSON object! That's because you're not assigning a string literal to it, but a javascript-object-structure.

Let's assume the string value of  the `"json"` attribute is `{ name: "Jack", age: 25 }`. Now after JSP processing has been done, the client receives the following:

```
var foo1 = { name: "Jack", age: 25 }
```

What you are maybe expecting is:

```
var foo1 = "{ name: \"Jack\", age: 25 }"
```